# (Angular) Destroying parent subscriptions from child

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription, unsubscribe

**//Parent component**

```
subscription: Subscription[] = [];

//stuff

constructor(private http: HttpService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  const subLoading = this.http.loading.subscribe((loading: boolean) => {
    this.loading = loading;
  });

//stuff to do

   this.subscription.push(subLoading);
   this.subscription.push(subData);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  console.log("logged if logging out directly from here")
  this.subscription.forEach((sub) => {
    sub.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

**//Child component**

Linked with a route from child to parent
(Parent URL : domain/list , eg.: Child URL: domain/list/item/53 )

**//App-routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: 'list/:pageID', component: ListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: 'list/item/:id',
    component: ListItemDetailComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

**//Header**

```
    export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public isLoggedIn = false;
  private userSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe((user) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = !!user ? true : false;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.userSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  logOut() {
    this.authService.logOut();
  }
}
```

In the **header** I unsubscribe,destroy the user(BehaviourSubject) and logOut

BUT many **BehaviourSubjects that I subscribed to in the Parent** component **doesnt get destroyed if I logOut while staying at the Child** Component

Any solution?

Comment: Could you provide a full picture of your code.

Comment: I added a bunch, hope its still followable, do you have any idea on the issue? Or other ways I could unsubscribe from the subscriptions made in the parent component?

Comment: If the list component route is still active, the component will not be destroyed. If you want to logout and stay in your list component then you could just use the authService to inform all your components about the logout and unsubscribe from a specific subscription. Otherwise if you navigate to a logout specific route then your list component will be destroyed and unsubscribe will be called onDestroy.

Comment: Try using something like: `destroyed$ = new Subject(); ngOnDestroy() { this.destroyed$.next(true); }` and `this.http.loading.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((loading) => {});`. This way you don't need to manage those annoying subscriptions

Comment: @MehyarSawas "if you navigate to a logout specific route then your list component will be destroyed"  What do you mean? To create a route for logout somehow?

Comment: @Pieterjan, will look into takeUntil thanks for the suggestion but my problem is still that the ngOnDestroy doesnt even get called

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but perhaps because `OnDestroy` isn't implemented? `implements OnInit, OnDestroy`

Comment: implementing an interface like OnDestroy is just for developing purpose and does not have any effect on the method call. Angular calls onDestroy if it finds it even when the interface is not implemented.

Comment: Angular destroy a component when it is not rendered in the html dom anymore. So if you still can see your list component after you logout. This means your component is still active. If you navigate somewhere else then your list component will be replace with the other component with Router and will be destroyed as soon as the other component is rendered in the router-outlet.

Answer (score 1):

just a point, you dont destroy BehaviourSubjects , you destroy subscriptions, thats why other componentes that have some subscription to the same behaviorSubject keep with their subscripcions.
I thing you can use other subject to emit when Logout, and use it in each subscripcion, with takeUntil() operator.
([takeUntil rxjs operator examples](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil))

Update: 
AuthService:

```
logoutSubject = new Subject(); // 
logout$ = this.logoutSubject.asObservable();
```

inside any component you want to take subscription of user until logout

```
this.authService.user
.pipe(takeUntil(this.authService.logout$)) // it will managing subscription until logout observable emit
.subscribe((user) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = !!user ? true : false;
    });
```

I think this should resolve your problem, but take in mind if you try to login again , that subscription do not work because has been terminated.

Comment: "use other subject to emit when Logout" can you elaborate on this? What other subject can I use on logout? How will that be related to the the ones I subscribed to in the parent component